# What organizational method or system do you use to manage SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate

One of the duties I've been recently assigned is to keep track of the SSL certificates used by the application servers I support. These are managed by external group mainly but internal to our department I'd like to have some way of storing them securely other than just on the server just as a precaution. I'd also like to keep track of when they expire, etc.

I've considered a key database (using some certificate tool like IBM Key Manager), or keeping them on an encrypted drive.

What I would like our suggestions for the best way to handle SSL certificates that doesn't risk exposing them to non-authorized individuals?

Answer (score 1):

I keep them in a git tree in a safe place. Where safe place can be an encrypted drive, or a machine only accessible by authorized people.